# Relation between counting measure and Tonelli theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

This is from Rudin's RCA book. But I can't understand how he got Corollary. What he takes as $f_n, X$? If we consider counting measure how integral converts to sum? I can't show this after some attempts.

Can anyone give a detailed answer please? I would be grateful for answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, $X = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ and $f_j(i) = a_{i, j}$. If $\mu$ is counting measure and
$$
f(i)
= \sum_{j=1}^\infty f_j(i)
= \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{i, j},
$$
then by Theorem 1.27 we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{i, j}
= \sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i)
= \int_X f \, d\mu
= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \int_X f_j \, d\mu
= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i, j}.
$$

**Edit.** A general fact about counting measure $\mu$ is the following: if $f : X \to [0, \infty]$ is measurable and $X$ is countable, then, interchanging summation and integration using Theorem 1.27 or the Monotone Convergence Theorem, we get
$$
\int_X f \, d\mu
= \int_X \left(\sum_{x \in X} f(x) \mathbf{1}_{\{x\}}\right) \, d\mu
= \sum_{x \in X} f(x) \int_X \mathbf{1}_{\{x\}} \, d\mu
= \sum_{x \in X} f(x) \mu(\{x\})
= \sum_{x \in X} f(x).
$$

Comment: Let me ask you one question: Why $\int \limits_{X}f_jd\mu=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i,j}$? Can you show it more detailed?

Comment: @RFZ please see my edit

Comment: 1) Why $f=\sum \limits_{x\in X}f(x)1_{\{x\}}$? How to show it rigorously? 2) Is it legal to carry out $f(x)$ from integral as you made after second inequality?

Comment: @RFZ 1) what I mean is that $f(y) = \sum_{x \in X} f(x) \mathbf{1}_{\{x\}}(y)$ for all $y \in X$. Note that $\mathbf{1}_{\{x\}}(y) = 1$ if and only if $y = x$, and it is zero otherwise. This way, the only contributing term in the sum is $f(y)$. 2) It is legal to carry $f(x)$ out of the integral because it is just a real number.

Comment: How? It's function on $x$.

Comment: @RFZ No, $f$ by itself is a function. $f(x)$ is $f$ evaluated at the point $x \in X$.

Comment: Where did we use that $X$ is countable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40287/discussion-between-rfz-and-artem-mavrin).

Answer (score 1):

Here $X=\mathbb N$

For $n=1,2,\dots$ let $f_{n}:\mathbb{N}\to\left[0,\infty\right]$
and let $\mu$ denote the [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure) on $\mathbb{N}$.

Define $f:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}$, in the sense that $f:\mathbb{N}\to\left[0,\infty\right]$
is prescribed by $k\mapsto\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}\left(k\right)$.

Then: $$\int fd\mu=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f\left(k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}\left(k\right)$$

According to the theorem we have also: $$fd\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int f_{n}d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_{n}\left(k\right)$$

Final conclusion:$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}\left(k\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_{n}\left(k\right)$$

Comment: Why $\int \limits_{X}f_nd\mu=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}f_n(k)$? How to get it from definition of Lebesgue integral?

Comment: Here $\mu$ is the "[counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure)" on $\mathbb N$. It is prescribed by $A\mapsto|A|$ for subsets of $\mathbb N$. That leads to the integrals as you describe in your comment.

Comment: Still don't understand. How you get that $\int \limits_{X}f_nd\mu=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}f_n(k)$? This seems to me very weird. Maybe you write how you get that equality?

Comment: I know the definition of counting measure but I don't understand how you get above equality?

Comment: Start by taking a look at the link to counting measure that I gave you.

Comment: I know the definiton! I am asking about equality. Can you show a detailed explanation?

Comment: Do you understand that $\int1_Ad\mu=\mu(A)=|A|=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}1_A(i)$?

Comment: Yes I do! but I don't how to prove strictly that $|A|=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{\infty} 1_A(i)$

Comment: If e.g. $A$ has $6$ elements then the RHS has $6$ times the term $1$ (for the $i\in A$) and further only has terms $0$ (for the $i\notin A$). It is just a matter of counting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40284/discussion-between-rfz-and-drhab).

Answer (score 0):

If we are in $(\Omega, F, \mu_c)$ where $\mu_c$ is the counting measure, the measurable function are of the form $f= \{a_i \}_{i\in \mathbb N}$ and $\int_\Omega f d\mu_c = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$

So that $f_j=\{a_{ij}\}_{i,j \in \mathbb N}$, thus using the Tonelli theorem in this setting, you get the thesis

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(i)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}$, with $f(i)=0$ whenever $i$ is not a positive integer, and $\mu(\{i\})=1$ for $i=1,2,\cdots$, and 0 otherwise. Now apply Tonelli's theorem.